# NAudio and DirectSound issue with calling Read method

Tags: c#, naudio

I have a `MoveTo` method which moves a cursor in my own `WaveProvider` class. I implemented a Phase Vocoder in this class, so when I move a cursor I need to recreate some objects with new values. There is no problem with `WaveOut`, but when I use `DirectSound`, it throws `ArgumentNullException`.
The problem is that, when program is in `MoveTo` method, and is changing some values inside object, `DirectSound` is inside Read method and it makes a crash. I tried to lock `WaveProvider` during changing position, but `DirectSound` still can get in Read method.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you locking on? You need to create a lock object inside your WaveProvider and lock on that during both your MoveTo and Read methods:

```
class MyWaveProvider : IWaveProvider
{
    private object lockObject = new Object();

    public void MoveTo(int pos)
    {
        lock(lockObject)
        {
            // perform the move
        }
    }


    public int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        lock(lockObject)
        {
            // perform the read
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After this my application freezes :(

Comment: are you calling MoveTo in response to an event raised within Read? You'll need to break in the debugger and look at stack traces to find what is causing your deadlock

Comment: I'll will try trace it, but now I don't know anything about it. I call MoveTo from GUI thread when I do a mouse click on my WaveForm control. I really don't know why DirectSound enters Read method even when I use lock (someObject). Hmm. Need to test more.